# How to share the same parameters between dependencies and endpoint functions?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to use the same parameters in my endpoint functions and dependencies.

I do something like this:

```
import fastapi
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


application = fastapi.FastAPI()


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    some_value: str
    
    @validator('some_value')
    def validate_some_value(value: str) -> str:
        if value == 'swearing':
            raise ValueError('The given value is invalid.')


def dependency_function(data: SomeModel) -> bool:  # Here is a parameter that will be used by an endpoint function.
    match data.some_value:
        case 'Hello':
            return True
        case 'World':
            print('Hello, World!')
            return False
        default:
            return False


@router.post('/some-endpoint')
async def send_value(
    data: SomeModel,  # I'd like this parameter to be shared between this endpoint and the dependency located below.
    data_is_valid: bool = fastapi.Depends(dependency_function)
):
    if data_is_valid:
        send_email_message('admin@gmail.com', data.some_value)
```

But this will work incorrectly. If we pass 'swearing' in the response body, the pydantic.ValidationError will be doubled. It means that something works incorrectly.

Please don't recommend that me to return a dictionary from dependency functions. I have dependencies that this approach is counterintuitive with.

Comment: The main issue is that raising a ValueError means that you can't cache the result of the dependency, since an exception gets thrown - it then attempts to resolve it again (otherwise, moving the `data` retrieval out to a dependency function like `def some_model_from_body(some_model: SomeModel):` and using `Depends()` on that value multiple places would work). Moving the `is_valid` decision under `SomeModel` or having it as a plain helper function would also resolve that (i.e. not as a dependency).

Comment: @MatsLindh sorry, I didn't understand your answer. Could you please explain again? Maybe it's because my English isn't very good..

Comment: Since a ValueError gets raised, FastAPI has no way of caching the resulting dependency, and will try to retrieve it again. The result of a `Depends` call is cached throughout the request, but since an exception is raised, it can't be cached - and thus, will be evaluated twice (otherwise we could rewrite "get me SomeModel" as a dependency and only have it evaluated once). Probably the best solution with that limitation in mind is to move the `some_model_is_valid` away from being a dependency and to either being a function or a method on the model.

Comment: Another option could be to modify the default exception handler to remove any duplicate errors; they will still occur twice, but only a single error will be returned to the user: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-request-validation-exceptions

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you very much for your answer, it was really helpful. If you want, put the info in an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you could rewrite this to be a single dependency that retrieves the input model from any way location using `Depends` - and which then gets cached. Something like:

```py
def some_model_from_body(some_model: SomeModel):
    return some_model


def some_model_is_valid(data: SomeModel = fastapi.Depends(some_model_from_body)) -> bool:
    pass


@application.post('/some-endpoint')
async def send_value(
    some_model: SomeModel = fastapi.Depends(some_model_from_body),
    some_model_is_valid: bool = fastapi.Depends(some_model_is_valid)
):
```

Tha way you end up with the dependency being evaluated only once. But since you're throwing an exception inside your validator, `Depends` won't cache the result and will try another time, triggering another exception. So this strategy **won't work** in this case.

The way to do this would then be to move away from the validation being a dependency, since you're not actually depending on that result - you're just using it to calculate a property of the submitted data, and we can use a regular function to do that work instead:

```py
def some_model_is_valid(some_model: SomeModel) -> bool:  # Here is a parameter that will be used by an endpoint function.
    pass


@application.post('/some-endpoint')
async def send_value(some_model: SomeModel):
    if some_model_is_valid(some_model):
        send_email_message('admin@gmail.com', some_model.some_value)
```

If this validation is something that is specific to the model, and not to these API endpoints, you can add it as a utility function on your model instead:

```py
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    some_value: str
    
    @validator('some_value')
    def validate_some_value(value: str) -> str:
        print("validating")
        if value == 'swearing':
            raise ValueError('The given value is invalid.')

    def is_valid(self):
        pass


@application.post('/some-endpoint')
async def send_value(some_model: SomeModel):
    if some_model.is_valid():
        send_email_message('admin@gmail.com', some_model.some_value)
```

Since you're not depending on whether the `is_valid` function is True or False, I feel like using Depends for that isn't really the way I'd do it. However, if you Depended on validation passing in this specific case, you could do a dependency that pre-validates it for you:

```py
def some_model_is_valid(some_model: SomeModel) -> bool:  # Here is a parameter that will be used by an endpoint function.
    if not some_model.is_valid():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400)

    return some_model


@application.post('/some-endpoint')
async def send_value(
    some_model_valid: SomeModel = fastapi.Depends(some_model_is_valid),
):
    send_email_message('admin@gmail.com', data.some_value)
```

So instead of depending on a model and then validating it, your view function now expresses that it "depends on a validated model" and can be re-used in other places that have the same requirement.

However, this assumes that the `is_valid` part is the only relevant action inside the view function - otherwise you'd want to do the `is_valid` check there instead.